# how to copy last 50 data point automatically from a master excel sheet to another excel sheet

Tags: excel

i have a masterwork sheet having 5 column (B12 To F12) and 500 +  (rows)data points. how to copy last 50 data point automatically to another sheet.

Comment: So I guess this has to be repeated and you want it automated? Alternatively, what is the difficulty in just finding the last 50 and copy-and-paste it to where you want it?

Answer (score 0):

In VBA and with the following assumptions for this example:

Your Data is in Sheet1 starting at B12

Your extracted Data set is copied to Sheet2 starting at B12

If there are less than 50 rows of data then all rows are copied

You can configure these parameters.

```
Sub CopyLast50()

Dim lRow As Long, sRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long, sCol As Long
Dim numRows As Long

'Configure these parameters
lCol = 6
sCol = 2
sRow = 12
numRows = 50

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row
            If sRow + lRow >= numRows Then
                .Range(.Cells(lRow, sCol).Offset(-(numRows - 1), 0), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(sRow, sCol)
            Else
                .Range(.Cells(sRow, sCol), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(sRow, sCol)
            End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Please take time to read the Tour of this site which can be found under Help.